# Array.prototype.reduce() Error After Including Initial Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am using `reduce()` in one of my functions to get a single value from some documents. Generally, this works as expected. However, once in a while I get an error "reduce is not a function". I know that, according to the docs, "Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error" -- so I am passing "0" to handle that. But I still sometimes - though rarely - get the error. Just trying to understand what's going on.

My code looks like this:

```
 let totalOpenBalance = docs.reduce((a, curr) => a + curr.openBalance, 0);
```

The data I'm calling this on looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "3s14020471287f4a9bbe9878",
        "openBalance": 120,
        "field3": 25
    },
    {
        "_id": "2d75020471986f4a9bbe7231",
        "openBalance": 15,
        "field3": 22
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message “reduce is not a function” has nothing to do with the arguments you pass to `reduce` – it is referring to the `docs.reduce` part of your code. This error message happens when the `reduce` property of `docs` is not a function as expected, but some other type of value such as `undefined`.

Since all arrays have a `reduce` function, that means that sometimes your `docs` variable is not an array. Add `console.log(docs)` before that line to see what type it is, and check where it is assigned to see why it is the wrong type.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll have to think through under what circumstance "docs" would not be an array. Even an array of 1 element should be fine, correct?

Comment: @Muirik Yes, an array with any number of elements including 1 or 0 would still have a `reduce` function.